# c# asp.net jquery modal button click not firing

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am exceptionally new to c# and asp.net however I have managed with some assistance from others to get a semi-good grounding on what does what, however, this has me stumped totally.

I have a search query that runs through Oracle, this works fine, however I want to be able to as a user to terminate the query after X amount of seconds (as some querys take a long time to complete)

I am capturing the page submit in Javascript to display a loader gif, this in turn calls another function which displays the modal and the terminate button.

Here is my  for my popup code:

HTML:

```
<div id="my_popup">

    <h2>Your search is taking a long time</h2>

    <asp:Button ID="btnStopSearch" runat="server" Text="Stop Search" OnClick="StopSearch_Click" OnClientClick="__doPostBack(ctl00$MainContent$btnStopSearch, '');"  />
</div>
```

Javascript

```
    function ShowLoading(e) {

        var divBg = document.getElementById('blockScreen');
        var divLoad = document.createElement('div');
        var img = document.createElement('img');

        img.src = 'images/ajax-loader.gif';
        divLoad.setAttribute("class", "blockScreenLoader");
        divLoad.appendChild(img);

        divBg.appendChild(divLoad);

        document.getElementById('blockScreen').style.display = 'block';

      //calls modal
        setTimeout(Moo, 2000)

    }


       function Moo() {
            //alert("Moo");
            jQuery('#my_popup').popup('show');


        }
```

Ive also set up a click event StopSearch_Click

```
{

    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connstr);
    using (OracleCommand objCmd = new OracleCommand())

        try
        {
            con.Open();

            objCmd.Connection = con;
            objCmd.CommandText = "webportal.pkg_webportal.setStopProcessingFlag";
            objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            objCmd.Parameters.Add("username", OracleType.VarChar).Value = PortalUser.Value;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add("status", OracleType.VarChar).Value = "Y";

            objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {

            con.Dispose();
        }


}
```

The package itself works fine when ran in PL/SQL and terminates the search, when its ran from the page itself I cannot get the button to fire and quite frankly Im out of ideas, i looked up __doPostBack but couldn't get my head around that either so any help is greatly appreciated as im banging my head against a wall.

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't need to handle OnClientClick here. Why are you doing this?

Comment: Is your click being hijacked by the blockScreen? It may be that you think your clicking a button but it is in fact a div element instead? try removing the show loading call just to test this out.

Comment: Andrei, - left over code from another test i think.

Comment: Andy - i will try that now.

Comment: Edit: removing the ShowLoading() and changing it to Moo() on click did nothing still nothing fires on the Modal button click.  I also removed the OnClientClick